# Draw Accelerometer x,y on ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, accelerometer

I just want to draw on image (canvas) using canvas.drawCircle statement where the the circle is determined the coordinates of Accelerometer values (x and y). 
The circle should appear once each time on get new data from accelerometer sensor.

Comment: great! use Canvas.drawCircle then

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've draw a circle using Canvas, but, there are many circles appear on imageview.. how can I show one circle (last one)?

Comment: draw a Bitmap and then drawCircle()

Comment: Call invalidate() (or postInvalidate() if not on the same Thread) on the ImageView so that it redraws itself, followed by then redrawing your new point onto the Canvas.